# Using SQLALCHEMY in my Python script

Tags: python, api, sqlalchemy

While using SQLalchemy engine APIs in my python script, I want to select few columns from a table with a where clause on the other columns. My query looks like following. I have successfully connected the engine. I know I am making some small mistake, please help

```
connection = engine.connect()
data=connection.execute("SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 =='India')
connection.close()
```

Comment: i dont think you need the double equality sign in the query

Comment: You have a missing " in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
connection = engine.connect()
s = text("select *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.Country = 'India'")
data=connection.execute(s)
```